# karate-gatling: report is not generated when gatling feeder and simulation workflow are failing due to a login request error

Tags: karate, gatling-plugin

If login error occurs during a gatling simulation (without feeders) normally a gatling report is generated showing that login request is failed. The login request is called only once in the `karate-config.js`: `karate.callSingle('classpath:login.feature', config);`

After defining a gatling feeder which executes a karate feature to retrieve some existing data from a database to be used during simulation, the gatling report is not generated if login error occurs during a feeder initialization.

I have tried the following workarounds:

- try-catch all exceptions in the feeder initialization
- force 2 login requests in the `karate-config.js`: one for feeder `karate.call()` and `karate.callSingle()` for other features

In both cases the gatling report is not generated due to `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`:

```
Caused by: UnsupportedOperationException: There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated
        at io.gatling.charts.report.ReportsGenerator.generateFor(ReportsGenerator.scala:49)
```

Although 2 login requests are logged in the `karate.log`.

So, what is a **proper way, to define feeders** (executing login feature) in a such way, **that login request is sent only once** for the whole simulation **and a report is generated even, if the login request is failed?**
As if a feeder hasn't been defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a feeder and call a Karate feature from that, as far as I know this is "outside" of the test from a reporting point of view. If it fails and the test stops, it is expected that you don't see any requests made at all. I don't see anything wrong with this personally, because a feeder is typically a one-time action that does not "count" when collecting metrics.

Kindly consider contributing to Karate since you seem to be pushing karate-gatling to limits I haven't seen before, thanks.

Comment: Peter, the second login request is failed during a simulation. So, I would expact to see it in the report. But if you say, it's normal. I don't insist on that.

Comment: @beloyar no worries - if you submit a proper way to replicate, I can look at it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue